# Why do packages exist to allow MySQL databases to connect to Python / R if we are just going to write SQL statements in Python / RStudio?

Tags: python, mysql, r

I initially wanted to create a MySQL database from scratch using an existing CSV file, and after doing exploratory data analysis, was going to use the functions in RStudio to allow me to do some more advanced statistical analysis.

After looking at a few guides, it seems that they all include connecting to the MySQL database, only to end up writing the `SELECT * FROM <database>....;` queries that could have been easily accomplished in MySQL in the first place.

For illustration,

https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/mysql-python

https://programminghistorian.org/en/lessons/getting-started-with-mysql-using-r

My question is twofold.

**1)** Why not just do everything in MySQL, instead of importing the tables into R / Python and then doing the same things  there?

**2)** For my situation (doing statistical analysis), is it still advisable to set up a connection to RStudio  to do my statistical analysis?

My end goal would be something along the lines of this.

1) Import database into RStudio.

2) Run statistical tests. Eg. `chisq.test(table1.column1, table2.column1)`

Is this possible? Or is my approach wrong in the first place?

Comment: If you have your data in a CSV file and can manipulate it as you want with R, what would be your reason to put the data in a db?

Comment: Yes, I do understand the inefficiencies behind this approach. I decided to start doing this to learn more about databases in general.

Comment: Hmm...if anyone could let me know why I got downvoted twice, that would be great. I don't think the question lacks effort, since I listed out my goals, added in references to justify my claims etc.

Comment: If you switch to MSSQL (I think Server > 2016 has R services) you could even put your R code `chisq.test()` "inside the database" - buzzword: 'closer to the data', nice feat for larger data and in corp env.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) If the queries needed are very simple, maybe pulling data into Python/R isn't necessary for your current use-case.

2) Similar to the first answer, if your use-case doesn't require it, then maybe not. If you plan on getting into deeper, more complex statistical analysis, then I think you will quickly realize that moving your data into Python/R is compulsory.

When you say "import database into RStudio", this is not possible. What is possible, is using a "MySQL connector" which allows you to execute MySQL queries on your database from Python/R.

[R MySQL Connector](https://db.rstudio.com/databases/my-sql/)
[Python MySQL Connector - PyMySQL](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL)

When you execute queries in Python/R using the MySQL connector, you will need to store this data somewhere so that you can manipulate it further. This is where data frames come in. Here is an [example](https://datatofish.com/sql-to-pandas-dataframe/) of loading data from MySQL into a Pandas data frame.

**Other Considerations**

There are a few considerations when balancing your workload between databases (SQL) and code (Python/R/etc.) As you mentioned, if all you need to do is run a quick one-time analysis or pull of data, MySQL may be all you need. However, as complexity increases, the following are some reasons to pull data from MySQL into code (Python/R)

***Debugging***
SQL is not easily debugged. Most GUI tools for SQL do not allow for stepping through code like Python/R for example, so finding issues becomes increasingly difficult as query complexity increases. With Python/R, you still can't directly debug your SQL code, but you can break your SQL queries into multiple different functions which can allow you to better pinpoint where issues occur.

***Version Control***
From my experience, queries and stored procedures written in companies are not under version control. So there is no running history of changes made. If you bring these queries into Python/R, then if any changes are made, they will most likely be under version control (because most people and companies are using GitHub/GitLab to version control their projects).

***Flexibility***
Python/R have so many packages and specific data structures to perform statistical analysis. It is of course a steeper learning curve to gain this knowledge, but the packages available are incredibly powerful.

***Complexity***
As your data and complexity of analysis grows, you may need more processing power than MySQL can handle. This is when you may need to begin using things like [Dask](https://dask.org/) and [Spark](https://pypi.org/project/pyspark/).

Comment: Thank you very much, as well as relating it to a company setting. When you say **moving data to Python / R**, do you mean connecting the database to Python/R and then doing the analysis? That brings me to a question I had from the post. Does this mean that R is capable of, say, something like `chisq.test(table1.column1, table2.column1)` when connected to the table? So far, all I have seen are `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` statements that I'm not sure if R supports these functions when connecting to the database.

Comment: Yes, when I say "moving data to Python/R", I mean that you will have a MySQL query that is run from Python/R, and this data will be loaded into a Pandas dataframe (Python) or an R dataframe. Once you have this, then you can proceed to doing your chi-square testing. I'm sure there are a lot of examples by googling things like "chi-square test in python", "chi-square test with pandas dataframe", etc. I personally have not done chi-square tests in R or Python, but I am almost certain you can do this. Any query that you can run on MySQL, you can also run in Python/R through a database connector.

Comment: I will try to add some of this information to my answer